# How can I 'continue' the outer most for loop when an if statement is satisfied?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, control-flow

How can I jump to the next value (not the next val) when the condition is satisfied?

Example:

```
lines = iter(open('something.txt', 'r'))
for value in list:
    for val in value:
        for v in val
            if v == "!":
            #execute code
            #jump to next value
```

Comment: I think you want `break`

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to stop the inner loop and go to next `value`:

```
lines = iter(open('something.txt', 'r'))
for value in lines:
    for val in value:
        if val == "!":
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the example, you can just break from the inner loop.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: You have to add `break` in place of the "#jump to next value" comment.